# Default text for TextInputLayout with AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I am using this to display a `Spinner` type of view for `TextInputLayout` but I am not getting how can I set any default value to it.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/primary_color_3">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/accType_dropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:text="@={viewModel.mytext}"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
        android:textColor="@color/name_primary_color"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The placeholder only works when it is in focus mode so please suggest a workaround.

Edit:

I am using two way data binding in this textview and it seems due to this  no solution is working in my case. Even i try to set default value for binded object then it automatically pop ups the spinner on application launch which i don't need so please suggest me something.

Answer (score 9):

The `AutoCompleteTextView` can work with an `Adapter`.

Just for example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til"
        ..>
               
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
       .../>


</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Create the adapter:

```
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add("Material");
    items.add("Design");
    items.add("Components");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.item, items);
    TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.til);
```

Set the default value and the adapter:

```
    ((MaterialAutoCompleteTextView) textInputLayout.getEditText()).setAdapter(adapter);
    ((MaterialAutoCompleteTextView) textInputLayout.getEditText()).setText(adapter.getItem(1),false);
```

It is important to set the filter `false` in **`setText(...,false)`** to
display the entire list in dropdown and not only the single value.

[image]

Comment: it seems you are setting up adapter for textinputlayout not on autocomplete textview...

Comment: @CosmicDev Check also the official doc: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextField.md#implementing-an-exposed-dropdown-menu

Comment: @CosmicDev Is not working = the default text is not visible?

Comment: Yes it is not visible

Comment: @CosmicDev It is the same because there `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` is auto-inflated by the material components library. It is important the order of `setText` and `setAdapter`. Otherwise use `setText(.... , false);`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Using a custom item layout removed the selected item's background color. I couldn't find any available item layout that does the job. According to my searches, the default layout only appears if we set it in the XML `app:simpleItems`. The default layout `mtrl_dropdown_item_text` is not accessible. Is there a way to imitate its' behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:text` attribute on `AutoCompleteTextView` like this

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                  
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/primary_color_3">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/accType_dropdown"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Select Something"
                        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="5sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/name_primary_color"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Putting `android:hint="text"` in the `TextInputLayout` also does the trick.

Comment: that will not act as default text.

Comment: @AgentP what if I am using data binding?